# How to change thank you message on php mailer

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I am following this little tutorial on setting up my own php mailer. It's here. http://www.tudor-anghelina.com/2013/09/how-to-create-php-bootstrap-3-contact.html

However in line 37 it has:

```
/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
exit();
```

I have no experience at PHP, but is there a way to just have a message saying "thanks for your message" on the same page as the form? I don't really want to be redirected to another .html page.

Comment: You need to use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) in that case. Since this isn't an easy thing to do, I suggest you search for [ajax contact form](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ajax+contact+form) and find something you can install instead of what you have already.

Comment: where is your line 37 ? How would i know ? Paste your code here, then only we can help.

Comment: line 37 is the code that I posted in the original post and I mentioned that too

Answer (score 0):

If you 'comment' the 2 lines below (by adding 2 slashes in front of each line) it will prevent the script from redirecting to the other page.

```
/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
//header('Location: http://address-of-confirmation-page.html');
//exit();
```

You will then have some more work to do, to:

1. clear the submitted information
2. hide the form
3. display a thanks message...

*You will need to show the code for any further help.*

Answer (score 0):

You can manually submit the form by using ajax and display the expected message based on the response.

You should also comment the above lines to avoid redirecting.